# Android Studio: Gradle Refresh Failed - Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've just pulled down an Android project from git, and Android Studio is giving me the following error whenever I attempt to open it;

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0-alpha6/gradle-2.2.0-alpha6.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0-alpha6/gradle-2.2.0-alpha6.jar
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0-alpha6/gradle-2.2.0-alpha6.pom
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0-alpha6/gradle-2.2.0-alpha6.jar
Required by:
    newApp_Android:app:unspecified
```

I've installed Gradle locally, and set up environment paths via System.

Under Project Structure/Project, the following setup is in use;

```
Gradle Version : 2.10
Android Plugin Version : 2.2.0-alpha6
Android Plugin Repository : jcenter
Default Library Repository : jcenter
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: Those urls didn't search JCenter, it looks like.  https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle

Answer (score 187, accepted):

This is because the build process is unable to find the dependency in Maven repository. Add **jcenter()** along with **mavenCentral()** in your project level **build.gradle** file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great for me, without replacing mavenCentral(), but just adding jcenter(). This made it unnecessary to go back to the old version of Gradle as is suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: You'll likely see performance increases in Android Studio if you remove `mavenCentral()` and only keep `jcenter()` for all dependencies in `build.gradle` - see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72061.  Note for project dependencies you may need to keep `mavenCentral()` if you have dependency artifacts not hosted on JCenter.

Comment: should I remove mavenCentral?

Comment: Could you explain why this works and not mavenCentral( )

Comment: @ArnoldRoa yes, you can remove mavenCentral()

Comment: @user3705478 you can see this link for more details: https://blog.bintray.com/2015/02/09/android-studio-migration-from-maven-central-to-jcenter/

Comment: @Bhavit S. Sengar thank you for improving description. However, I am not sure that you need mavenCentral() for project level build.gradle file.

Answer (score 9):

So I had a similar error while I was trying to build ionic2 project for android. This happened after android studio updated gradle during its updates.

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApk'.
  >   A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
  >   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
  >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
  >          Searched in the following locations:
  >              https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
  >              https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
  >          Required by:
  >              android:CordovaLib:unspecified

I read the above answers which pointed to update a 'build.gradle' file but turns out there were multiple files with that name in the project. What worked for me (and hopefully helpful to whoever is working on angular2/ionic2 project and having this issue) is updating the build.gradle file at

```
[rootOfPorject]/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle
```

This file was missing the jcenter() entry and now the repository part looks like this and works like a charm.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Hope this saves time for someone else.

**EDIT**: As @rcerecedar mentioned, you might also need to add `jcenter()` in the following file as well.

```
[rootOfPorject]/platforms/android/build.gradle
```

In this file you should check its present in `buildscript -> repositories` and also optionally in `allprojects -> repositories`

Comment: Thnaks a lot. It helped me, but, in the end, I had to insert the jcenter() line in BOTH files, the "main" build.gradle and, the one in Cordovalib.

Comment: Thanks @rcerecedar I have updated my answer to include this information too.

Answer (score 4):

1.Goto "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle"

2.See the Latest folder name , i.e "2.2.3" , Copy It.

3.Go to build.gradle(Module:yourapp) file ,

Place here:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have firewall configured in your  PC,try the following in gradle.properties.

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<proxyHostName>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=<user id>
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=<password>
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=www.google.com|localhost
```

Comment: Where is gradle.properties located at?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was i did exactly what "geekydhaval" said, thanks again for that but I went back to the  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0' } and change from 2.3.2 to 2.3.0 and the build completed successfully.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment, please stick to concrete questions and answers which require no clarification from the author.

Comment: Thanks. but always give answers here. No other stuffs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `gradle:2.2.0-alpha6` to `gradle:2.2.0-alpha3`.
If this doesn't work replace it to `gradle:2.2.0-alpha2`.

Answer (score 0):

As gradle is updating the previous version will be replaced with new version so we have to change the gradle version in code as it would be referring to previous version and will show error like this

> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> >     Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
> >      Searched in the following locations:
> >          file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
> >          file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
> >          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
> >          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
> >          https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
> >          https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
> >      Required by:
> >          :: Open file

The solution to this is that we add the repository in the build.gradle file
like

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

OR

GOTO the File Explorer and search

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle
```

and see the Gradle name with latest version like

```
Gradle 2.2.0
Gradle 3.2.1
Gradle 2.1.0
```

and select the latest version like `3.2.1` and paste it in the `build.gradle` file in `dependencies` section like

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'}
```