# Gradle error : Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3

Tags: android, gradle, circleci

I'm trying to build my android project using gradle and circleCI, but I've got this error :

```
* What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project '<myproject>'.
  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
 Searched in the following locations:
     file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
     file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
 Required by:
     :<myproject>:unspecified
```

Can someone explain me why I've got this problem please?

Comment: Please go to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347) and star it.

It seems there are a lot of problems because there were a lot of libraries unpublished from jCenter.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It seems the current versions of the Android Gradle plugin are not added to Maven Central, but they are present on jcenter. Add `jcenter()` to your list of repositories and Gradle should find version `2.2.3`. On Maven Central the newest available version is `2.1.3`: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.android.tools.build%22%20AND%20a%3A%22gradle%22. You can also complain to the authors that the current versions are missing on Maven Central.

Comment: I added jcenter() to my repo lists, and it worked. I hope that the devs will bring the updated package to mavenCentral quickly

Comment: @girod_s as there are several versions missing (all `2.2` versions), maybe they either decided to not server Maven Central any longer or they are not aware that it is not distributed to Maven Central. If they did not announce that Maven Central will not be served any longer, you should probably report to the devs that it is missing.

Comment: Yes, I asked for an explaination in gradle's forum. Thanks !

Comment: I don't think the Gradle forum is the proper place. The Android Gradle plugin is not developed by the Gradle team but by Googles Android team, isn't it? So you would need to report to them, not to Gradle.

Comment: This worked for me (adding jcenter() ...)  Here's the "why":
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852219/android-buildscript-repositories-jcenter-vs-mavencentral

Answer (score 25):

Reading sembozdemir answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702032/android-studio-gradle-refresh-failed-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildg/38702115) I have resolved a similar problem adding jcenter() in build.gradle (module: cordovaLib)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 25):

After the recent update to **Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1**, I got the following error:

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha1/gradle-3.0.0-alpha1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha1/gradle-3.0.0-alpha1.jar
     Required by:
         project :
```

Here is what I had to add (to the *project-level* build.gradle):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        ....            
    }
```

Found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html

Comment: You could also use as oppose to explicitly add the google maven repo the newly added "google()" repository.

Answer (score 11):

i had the same issue when i update my android studio to 3.0 then its solved by adding

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
    ...
    // You need to add the following repository to download the
    // new plugin.
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
}
 }
```

from https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#update_gradle

Comment: It seems that if you are using jcenter() and google(), google repository have to precede jcenter.

Answer (score 9):

On my side I got the same issue because I used the wrong order of repositories.

**google() should be added before jcenter()**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
buildscript {
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
}

}
```

Just change the mavenCentral() to jcenter()

Answer (score 4):

Do you try it

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }

    }

}
```

and 
    Build->Clear Project

Comment: which file is that ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools"
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: If you happen to suddenly run into this issue since 12/10, read the following issue comments to see the causes: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment30, and proposed solution in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment80

Answer (score 1):

Updating **CordovaLib** -> build.gradle also worked for me, as above. I was looking at the root build.gradle initially which was correct and already included jcenter().

Answer (score 1):

Only go to the following path and delete the **caches** folder completely then rebuild the project:

> C:\Users\[Your User Name]\.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Change the gradle version as same to android version like Right know we are using 2.3.2 of gradle

Answer (score 0):

Add jcenter in your project gradle file and sync

[image: check this for refernce]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by your type of internet connection which prevents or blocks Android Studio from downloading required files from jcenter, this should happen automatically when you build your solution. The solution to your problem is to connect to internet using your personal internet connection such as ADSL Router, rebuild the project and the download of necessary files will happen automatically.

Comment: Do this after adding jcenter() inside the repositories{}