# Could not found com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

Hello I am following the material design course from Udacity when i downloaded the code they provide in Lessons but when i open it in Android it gives me that error

```html
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
Required by:
    :ApplyPaletteDemo:unspecified
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570435/gradle-error-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle2-2-3/41570960) you will solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your build.gradle file for your project matches your version of Android Studio. It is possible that the project was written for an older version of Android Studio.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "http://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made it but this error occure                                                                     **Error:(1, 0) Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in E:\ApplyPaletteDemo\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip
<a href="openFile:E:\ApplyPaletteDemo\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>**

Comment: Download the last version from https://gradle.org/releases after that go to file/project structure/project and put the new version in gradle version

Comment: I Downloaded gradle version 4.1 and added the extracted folder in the .gradle file and open file/project structure / project and edited gradle version but it gave me same error I don't know the reason

Comment: I changed the version of gradle from 2.3.3 to 2.2.3   and works correctly Thanks @Chad H for your support