# Not able to download Gradle plugin in the Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am not able to work with the gradle dependencies on the MAC.

I am getting this error : 
Could not GET

'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0/gradle-2.0.0.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required

Its a proxy issue. 
I have though set the proxy in the gradle.properties as well and in the Settings>Https as well.

I am able to download the SDK but not the gradle plugin.
If i try to click the link in the error , I get redirected to the gradle site (on Safari) and 1Kb of pom file gets downloaded itself.
I am wondering that somehow the safari application has the correct setting for the proxy thats why it is able to downloaded the pom file 
but from within the android studio , somewhere authentication is failing and hence it is failing.
Is there any other place i have to put the proxy or any test to test the correct way of working the proxy from within the Android Studio.

already added jcenter in build.gradle :

```
 jcenter() {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
```

I have already checked the "check connection" by providing the url(which came in the error) -> 
and it says connection successfull.
WHats the hidden mystery here to solve this issue?
thanks in advance !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570435/gradle-error-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle2-2-3/41570960 check this...Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Add jcenter() to your list of repositories and Gradle should find version 2.0.0