# Error while building Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to build my android project it shows some gradle error. The error is as follows,

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
Required by:
    D4D.libs:ViewPagerIndicator-Library:unspecified
```

If anybody know how to fix this error please help me.

my **build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle error : Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570435/gradle-error-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle2-2-3)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the build process is unable to find the dependency in Maven repository. Add **jcenter()** along with **mavenCentral()** in your project level **build.gradle** file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}
```

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654136/5049244)

Answer (score 0):

according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654136/8284461, maybe you need to add `mavenCentral()` in your repositories. the gradle would be like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```